# Django проблемы с формой

Tags: django

У меня есть две модели

```py
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('City', max_length=50)
    temperature = models.ForeignKey('Temperature', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Cities'


class Temperature(models.Model):
    temperature = models.IntegerField('Temperature')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.temperature)
```

Есть форма в которой нужно выводить все города из базы данных и показывать их температуру, так не получается, как реализовать?

```py
class CitySelectForm(forms.ModelForm): # НЕ РАБОТАЕТ
    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = ['name']

        widgets = {
            'name': forms.Select()
        }
```

Comment: Это надо две отдельные формы делать. Вообще странно, что у вас соотношение один ко многим. У вас одна температура будет на много городов?

Comment: В общем, если оставить все так, как есть, то можно задавать одной температуре много городов в виде форм с помощью `inlineformset_factory`, но имхо у вас неправильно построена схема бд. Я не вижу в этом логики

Answer (score 0):

У вас отношение один (температура) ко-многим (города). Каким образом вы из формы, имеющей отношение к City, пытаетесь вывести через select несколько городов, если у вас name - это единичное поле (char).

Может быть только наоборот - выбор через select температуры.

Делайте через `modelformset`, причем `modelformset` должен создаваться из формы где есть выбор температуры.

```python
class CityForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = ['name', 'temperature']

CitiesFormSet = modelformset_factory(City, form=CityForm)
```

или еще проще

```python
CitiesFormSet = modelformset_factory(City, fields=('name', 'temperature'))
```